# Python Regex: Can't extract message containing escaped quotes

Tags: python, regex

I'm creating a bot for Slack, and it needs to be able to extract the message from a string of data that looks like this:

```
[{'text': 'This is my legit "test" \'message\' with "lots" of \'quotation marks\'', 'type': 'message', 'user': '<userID>', 'channel': '<channelID>, 'ts': '1450501889.000074', 'team': '<teamID'}]
```

My current regex is this:

```
re.search(r''''text': (["'])(.*?)\1''', channelstatus)
```

How can I make it output only the following?

```
This is my legit "test" 'message' with "lots" of 'quotation marks'
```

Comment: Why not use a JSON parser?

Comment: see https://regex101.com/r/sY8eR9/1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need for regular expressions - [`ast.literal_eval()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) can handle that:

```
>>> from ast import literal_eval
>>>
>>> s = r'''[{'text': 'This is my legit "test" \'message\' with "lots" of \'quotation marks\'', 'type': 'message', 'user': '<userID>', 'channel': '<channelID>', 'ts': '1450501889.000074', 'team': '<teamID'}]'''
>>> print(literal_eval(s)[0]["text"])
This is my legit "test" 'message' with "lots" of 'quotation marks'
```

<sup>Assuming that there was a missing quote after the `<channelID>` by accident.</sup>